# Lookup Data in Java

Tags: java, database

I am writing an application that needs to look up data from a table (20x200) for calculation inputs. The table is filled with constants (i.e. I do not need to write to the table). I am still a novice programmer and have not had a lot of experience with databases, and so prior to proceeding I would like to know the best way to achieve this.

I had intended to place the data in an array and simply perform the lookup with 2 loops (one row look up and one column lookup) however I feel this is very inefficient. Is it worth looking into A database such as SQLite? or is that overkill for what is a relatively small data set with no requirement for editing?

Comment: Just save your array as a CSV file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As often, the answer is: It depends.

1. Do you need some advanced querying, like the sum of all values in the x column for which the value in the y column is greater then 23. If so a in memory SQL database comes in handy. Otherwise it would just be overkill.
2. Assuming the database is out of the discussion, the next questions are: Do you need single values, complete (or large parts of) columns or rows? And what are the natural "names" of your columns and rows.

Here are some options:

**"names" are continuous integers**: Use a 2D array (I wouldn't use arrays very often in Java, but in a read only situation with fixed lengths everything else sounds like to much overhead. By choosing the order of the indices, i.e. rows first vs. columns first you can get complete columns/rows very easy and efficient.

**"names" are not continuous, Strings or any other objects**: Use a Map of Maps if you need access to complete rows or columns. If you only need single values, create a Pair type and use it a the key for the map.

Comment: Thanks for all the responses. I think a 2d array will end up as the simplest option. I have numeric data in the table with each column headed by an int (which is the basis of the column lookup) and each row named with a string. For user input I will list the row names in a JList in my GUI which can be used to provide a row index.

Answer (score 0):

1) You can use a in-memory database like [H2-Datbase Engine](http://www.h2database.com/html/main.html).
For which you just need to include a jar and data retrieval will be very fast.
It can't be considered as an overhead on your application.

2) Or you can use a Map<key,Map<String,string>> for the lookup.

For the main Map, key will be your record id, and for inner Map key will be your column name.

Whether to make it static or not I leave that on you to decide.

3) You can also explore caching options like ehcache.